# How to use gsub to extract the id of a youtube video?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

I have to extract http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**aNdMiIAlK0g** the video id from this url. Anyone know how do this using gsub and regex?

Comment: Someone's trying to do the same thing in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903854/how-can-i-alter-this-regex-to-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-a-youtube-url-that-do)

Comment: Sometimes there could be short url like http://youtu.be/aNdMiIAlK0g which you might consider here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match the `v` parameter with this regexp:

```
url[/(?<=[?&]v=)[^&$]+/] # => aNdMiIAlK0g
```

It starts with a lookbehind for `?` or `&` and matches everything up until the next `&` or the end of the string. It works even if there are other parameters, even those ending in "v".

However, a safer way to do it might be to use the URI class:

```
require 'uri'

query_string = URI.parse(url).query
parameters = Hash[URI.decode_www_form(query_string)]
parameters['v'] # => aNdMiIAlK0g
```

Answer (score 2):

this is it:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNdMiIAlK0g"[/v=([^&]+)/, 1]
 => "aNdMiIAlK0g"
```

(although you may want to use the URI library to get the query part and split them using `&` and use the value for `v`, because the above will get confused if the url is something like http://www.youtube.com/promo?for_tv=1 and it will take it as `v=1`)

Comment: thanks man, I tryed this and got the result too : str.match(/v=([\w|-]*)&*/)[1]